# Get a 1132px panel to center in a 1024px screen without scroll?

Tags: css

I want to have a 1024px width website with a gradient background image. I have a panel that's 1132px wide because I want widescreen resolutions to see where the panel ends. However, I do not want a scroll bar.

So imagine a 1024px square, and a 1132px panel centered through it. on a 1024px wide screen/browser it seems the panel never ends without a horizontal scrollbar but when you look at it on a 1280px wide screen you'll see the panel ends. Can anyone help me achieve this? IE6 compatible preferred. Thank you!

Comment: try centering it using absolute positioning and setting `overflow: hidden`... not sure how it'll work with IE 6; i personally stopped supporting IE 6 when http://www.ie6countdown.com/ came out

Comment: We're a big company and trying to keep up with everyone, but you're right about IE6 being a hassle. The overflow hidden didn't work. Not even for modern day browsers. :\ I have html set to background gradient. 1024px div margin auto, inside that I have the 1132px panel set to absolute and overflow hidden, screen size is still being forced to scroll to 1132px.

Comment: As Hristo mentions centering with `overflow-x: hidden` would be the best approach. But IE6 doesn't support this. Unless you need to support China there is really no point. Let us know if you absolutely must support IE6 and then maybe there is a hack out there.

Comment: We'll drop IE6 and let the mobile site handle IE6. So a universal work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combining the usual centering technique with `overflow-x: hidden;` seems to do the trick:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
#content {
  width: 900px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -450px;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/brianpeiris/RRqAq/show

Comment: Great! Thank you, the part that did it was the left: 50 and the negative margin left of half the screen size. Wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

how about just prompting your IE6 users to download a better browser or to install google chrome frame, after all it will be better for everyone, you , users, developers ....

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]><p class=chromeframe>Your browser is <em>ancient!</em> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade to a different browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to experience this site.</p><![endif]-->
```